# Misbehavior of UITableView willDisplayCell method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There is a `UITableView` of posts.
Seen posts id's are saved in sqlite
I want to show, seen posts in orange color and others in black.
But when I set orange color for seen post in `willDisplayCell` method some cells are colored orange incorrectly, otherwise the print log ("Color it") is correct.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let post = postDataSource.posts[indexPath.row]
    print(post.id)
    let cellPost = cell as? PostListViewCell

    if post.isRead.boolValue == true {
        print("Color it")
        cellPost!.body.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        cellPost!.title.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
}
```

For instance, if just one post is seen, "Color it" is printed once. and it's correct. But some other cells are colored orange without "Color it" log.

Comment: Any specific reason as to why not use CellForRowAtIndexPath to style the cells ?

Comment: Use custom cells

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I used CellForRowAtIndexPath in DataSource and I don't want to set style in DataSource

Comment: then create function called configCell in your cell subclass and call configCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This is cleaner because cell is responsible for setting its own style :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try completing the if statement

```
 if (post.isRead.boolValue == true) {
    print("Color it")
    cellPost!.body.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    cellPost!.title.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}else{
    cellPost!.body.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cellPost!.title.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to do this. I know that it fixes the problem but why I need to color black again when the default color is black

Answer (score 1):

**1.Understanding of Reusable table-view cell object**

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell)

For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally reuse
**UITableViewCell**
objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
**tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)**
method. A table view maintains a queue or list of
UITableViewCell
objects that the data source has marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view.

> This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates
> a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered.

If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.

**2.Usage of prepareForReuse()**

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method
**dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)**
. For performance reasons,

> you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
> content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state.

The table view's delegate in
**tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)**
should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.

Another way to do manually resetting attributes of the cell which already described by @RJiryes.